# Asp.Net website looking fine in IE6 but not in IE7/IE8

Tags: asp.net, webforms, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8

I have a small website developed using VS2005 and mySQl, it's just 2 webforms and login page.

During the development and testing phase, me and my customer were using IE6, and it was looking fine, we didn't test with other browsers because it's a small application, and just a add-in for large desktop application.

The customer informed me that site doesn't like the same when he installed IE7, for example I have a webfrom that show a page with Gridview that has multiply pages(AllowPaging=On), it doesn't look fine in IE7 and I can't navigate to other pages in Gridview, but it was working fine with IE6, and there's no complicated things, just plan GridView with small formatting.

I installed IE8 and doesn't look fine with it too, even in compatibility mood.

Have anyone faced the same problem?, and what should be the quickest or best solution for that?.

I know, **I SHOULD NEVER USE WEBFORMS AGAIN.**

Comment: Could you post the .aspx?
It's hard to solve the problem without seeing the code.. unless you can reproduce the problem by dragging a gridview in a blank page.. which I doubt.

Comment: "Never again" is for IE6, not Webforms.

Comment: Web forms are fine, your styling/html is what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason for a difference in look between the browser versions is your styling and doctype.

Start with setting a doctype to run in quirks mode.  You can get information [about it here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/).

After that, see if things improve.  If not, I would start ripping out any css/styles/themes you may be using.  Then build it back up using normal CSS.

Incidentally, web forms isn't the problem in this case; it's a styling issue.

Answer (score 2):

as Chris mentioned, add to that that browsers have really some annoying differences that makes you pull your hair sometimes, and 90 % of the time it is related to CSS.

so what i suggest is the following

- use a tool called IE Tester, it is amazing tool that let you test your sites in all IE versions.
- Use conditional command for targeting IE specific version if some CSS rule is wrong.
- we use this tool http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ it is really amazing it let you define css rules for each browser without hacking or conditional statement, but the down side it is Javascript dependent, but we had no complains.
- also this script http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/  which is brilliant, it will let IE 6 behave like IE 7 which will save you tons of problems, again it is Java Script dependent.
- Avoid Hacks as much as possible, the above methods will help you a lot.

hope this helps.

Comment: Great additional suggestions +1.

Comment: glad i helped out, it is really tough now a days